# Android studio project creation

Tags: android-studio

Iam getting the following error message "Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later." when i tried to create a project using android studio help me out 
I have update my SDK version to 22 still Iam facing this issue

Comment: what operating system? is your SDK installed in the default directory? if not have you added the SDK to your system PATH?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - SDK is out of date or is missing templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates)

Answer (score 3):

Try

- Selecting `Configure->`, then `Project Defaults->`, then `Project Structure`.
- Selecting `Project` in left pane and then `Android SDK` under the `Project SDK` menu on the right.
- Then click on `Edit` button [or just select `SDK's` on the left panel].
- Set/Verify the Android SDK home path (mine is `/opt/android-studio/sdk`, the Build target (mine is Android 4.2.2) and the Java SDK (mine is 1.7).
- Click OK, and back up to the `Quick Start` window. You should now be able to create a new project.