# running Android Studio on Windows 7 fails, no Android SDK found

Tags: java, android, sdk, installation, android-studio

I've downloaded and installed Android Studio, the program loads (after setting the [JDK env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)) but when i click on "New Project" i get this error :

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure
>   you are using SDK version 22 or later.

the android SDK is included with Android Studio in this location : **C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk** but it seems he dosen't find it,

android SDK or eclipse was not installed previously,
anyone installed Android Studio and got/solved this error!!

Comment: do you have any environment variables set that are related to android?  Maybe it looks at those before the installation directory.

Comment: no, it's a clean windows installation and i have not installed older android sdk or eclipse...

Comment: First, check your JDK variable.

Then, check this post >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ok, here's how it worked:

I downloaded the Adt bundle and Copied the file "SDK Manager.exe" to the Android studio root directory and just executed it (this set the SDK environment variable to **C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk**).

then In Android studio clicked **Configure** ==> **Project Defaults** ==> **Project Structure**

then in the tab **Project** / **Project SDK** selected **android SDK**.

then in the tab **SDKs** / **build target** selected Android 4.2.2

Comment: Dint fix the problem. Its still showing no Android SDK found.