# No Android SDK found - Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a problem with Android 0.4.2 Studio, when creating a new application, it tells me there is a problem with the rendering and shows me the following problem:

Renderering Problems
No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android SDK.

My setup SDK and JDK is this: Android SDK location: C:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk, I put the path I use in Eclipse SDK, or there may be the problem, if someone has happened and what has been fixed, I'd like to give me the solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered and solve a similar problem.

First you should check the directory like other threads described. Then you can check whether the *Build tool version* matches your SDK version.

(e.g. for my project, in build.gradle file, you have:)

> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 21
>       buildToolsVersion "21.1.1" }

and then open you SDK manager, make sure you have the same version of sdk(21.1.1) installed in the selected directoriy:

If not, install it and restart Android Studio. It works for me.

I've also seen other guys saying run Android Studio as administrator would also help:

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/i-am-getting-this-warning-message-rendering-problems-no-android-sdk-found-please-configure-an-android-sdk

Answer (score 3):

I got the same "No Android SDK Found" error message... plus no rendering for Design window, no little cellphone screen.

My SDK path was correct, pointing to where the (downloaded during setup) SDK lives.

During Setup of the SDK Mgr, I didn't download the latest "preview edition (version 20)"...(I thought it better to use the next most recent version (19))  Later I found, there was no dropdown choice in the AVD Manager to pick Version 19, only the default value of the preview, 20.

I thought "Maybe the rendering was based on a version that wasn't present yet." So, I downloaded all the "preview edition's (version 20)" SDK Platform (2) and system images (4)...

Once download/install completed, 
RESTARTED Android Studio and Viola! success... error message gone, rendering ok.

Answer (score 2):

From the **File** menu, choose **Project Structure** (if you're running 0.4.4 there's a bug and the menu item doesn't have a title, but it still works), and choose the **Android SDK** item. You should see something like this where you can set up your JDK and SDK.

[image: Project Structure dialog, Android SDK tab]

After setting it, quit Android Studio and relaunch it for good measure.

Comment: I have the same default settings, in my case I use windows, and the path is C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk, and JDK is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51 apparently got it all right, and I installed the necessary SDKManager and still the problem, I think I'll be better once more with Eclipse .. :l

Answer (score 2):

i have just discovered, android studio 3.0.1 has no sdk during the installation. because during the installation, it doesn't give sdk as part of install able unlike in recent versions of android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry just change the

```
build.gradle
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
```

to previous version.
It worked for me hope it works for you too. 
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android Studio download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), the SDK comes bundled with Android Studio. It has its own copy when you install Android Studio.

ADT is a plugin for Eclipse. Try reading through that webpage to see if there is something that got missed when installing.

Here is the wording from the site, regarding ADT:

> Similar to Eclipse with the ADT Plugin, Android Studio provides integrated Android developer tools for development and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share a part of the issue I had because it is the first google result.

I installed Android Studio, when I tried to install my first SDK from the SDK Management windows I got the error that I didn't have any SDK installed.
I tried to look on the internet to manually download the .zip,manualy create the folder, no luck what so ever.

When I tried to run the Android Studio as an administrator it detected I didn't have any SDK and prompt me right away at startup to download a SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps

a) Change minSdkVersion and sync gradle

b) Revert back your minSdkVersion and sync gradle again

It will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

These days, Android Studio setup do not provide SDK as the part of original package.

In the context of windows, when you start Android Studio 1.3.1, you see the error message saying no sdk found. You just have to proceed and provide the path where sdk can be downloaded. And you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this bug changing the proxy configuration:

```
No proxy → Auto-detect proxy settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution just copy your `SDK Manager.exe` file at the root folder of your android studio's installation, Sync your project and cheers... here is the link for details.
[running Android Studio on Windows 7 fails, no Android SDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599531/running-android-studio-on-windows-7-fails-no-android-sdk-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try make New Project, and then choose same android version that you've installed sdk verions on "Target Android Device" dialog.
In my case, error message gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Android Studio just could not identify the android-sdk folder. All I did was to uninstall and reinstall android studio, and this time it actually identified the folder. Hope it also works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Download android sdk through this sdk manager https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
(note this link is for mac)
open android studio, click next, open where it ask to add path where u downloaded sdk..... add it... click next, it will downloaad updates..... and it done

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the last version of Android Studio bundled (*Windows IDE bundle with SDK (64-bit)*) with Android SDK is **version 2.3.3**:

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html#android-studio-2-3-3

which size is about 2GB.

You can use it and then upgrade to the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: Not sure if that really answers the question ... (also not sure why this was downvoted on the other hand)

Comment: It solves the error "No Android SDK found".
I just tried it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I am on Mac Os. In my case, my host file was black. I added following entries (these entries should be there by default, but they weren't).

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255     broadcasthost
::1                          localhost
```

After re-running android studio, it prompted the sdk download.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when installing android studio, it said Android SDK unavailable and the reason was simple. You cannot download the SDK locally in the root folder of your device. I changed the location of the folder to my D drive ( you can do this step after installation is complete by going to tools or more options) and it worked. It installed the SDK and connected.