# Android Studio - Android SDK out of date

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I am getting an "SDK is out of date" error. I've seen a few other posts mention something about editing a path variable but I'm not really sure what this means. If someone could explain what I need to do to get past this error I'd really appreciate it! Thanks

[image: Error message]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - SDK is out of date or is missing templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your default project settings. Go to File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure. Change the Project SDK setting to Android SDK. This should clear the error for all new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ANDROID_SDK_DIR/tools/android` and update Android SDK tools to version 22, Platform and Build tools to version 17.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and the error returned is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file". Do you know what could be causing that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is caused by trying to interpret Java byte code compiled for newer version of Java (for instance 7) with incompatible older Java Runtime (for instance 6). Check your JDK or JDKs.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to Android and Java. How do I check my JDK - and if it's out of date, how to I update it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix (Linux/MacOS X), this seems like permission problem. Someone who packed Android Studio, has the original files under non-root account. If you unpack it as root, the files and dirs has no permission for "other" (just for owner). The person who is packing Android Studio knows a lot about Android and Java, but not much about Unix permissions (uch!). There are two possible solutions:

a) unpack android-studio-bundle-...-linux.tgz as normal user, not as root (this has an advantage - you will be able to update Andriod Studio by clicking menu; but this is generally stupid because you are open to malware attack)

b) fix read permissions for files and dirs for whole android-studio directory with something like: chmod -R 755 /opt/android-studio (not ideal because all files has "x" then, but it  works)