# Android Studio SDK Version 22?

Tags: android, android-studio

Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later.

The machine I'm using I've not had Eclipse on before, but had to because of the SDK Issue,

I've installed

SDK 64bit here:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

SDK 32bit here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

Android-Studio is install here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio
```

Eclipse

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\Eclipse
```

Now on another part of this forum a nice post said to change the settings in `Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structures`, but I'm not to sure what to change. I did go into project in (project settings), the list in there is:

- None
- 1.7 (java version 1.7.0_21)
- Android SDK (java version 1.7.0_21)

I selected  Android SDK (java version 1.7.0_21). Then there are the `NEW` and `Edit` buttons. But when I try to give it a path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21` etc it says it's incompatible.

My environment variables are:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

Does anybody know how to fix this???

Comment: Android sdk is different from Java. You have not installed Android SDK, download and install from http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22-windows.exe and change your settings accordingly

Comment: Thanks I'm doing this now, it would of been nice if they included it in the original Android Studio download, or even said about it! so do i have to do anything once this has been downloaded and installed change any settings? for example that i've done?

Comment: yes look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates

Comment: this folder does not exist!! Windows: \Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Anroid\android-studio\sdk\ I'm asumming I need to change my enviroment variables to point to the Android-sdk thats here C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk ??

Comment: finally got it to working cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure that inside Configure > Projects Defaults > Projects Structure > Click on the "Android SDK" section at the bottom left panel and insert the path of your Android SDK like this: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk (Use the browser to point to the sdk folder).

Answer (score 1):

`Android SDK` is different from `Android API level`.

I had this issue when i tried to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio IDE.
The problem is the version of **Android SDK Tools** as the error message supposes.

*Presuming you have installed Android SDK from Eclipse before*:

```
1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help->Check For Updates and update to latest version (just to be sure)
3. Go to Window->Android SDK Manager
4. on the SDK Manager make sure you have selected Tools.Android SDK Tools,Platform-tools and SDK Build-tools![first 3 on the picture][1]
5. Press 'Install packages'
6. Restart Eclipse and Package Manager
7. Repeat steps 4, 5 and 6 until there is nothing left to update.
8. Close Eclipse, start Android Studio and try to 'create new project' again. This time it should work!
```

*If you are able to start Android Studio, you can open SDK Manager from there (in the toolbox by defaut), and go on from p.4*

if using Eclipse also be sure to have set the SDK path the same as in Eclipse

> Android Studio - configure - Project Defaults - Project structure - Press plus- Android SDK - put path to the same sdk that you use in eclipse (run SDK and in top panel you can see this path) [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates)

Answer (score 0):

In your `eclipse`

Go to `Help` → `Install New Software`.

On Work with: type `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` and press `ENTER`.

Wait for Eclipse to fetch the repository. An item named Developer tools will appear in the list.
Mark it for install, press Next and follow the steps to install the `ADT` tools.

When finished, it will ask to restart Eclipse. Make sure you do this.

When Eclipse restarts, all your Android SDK packages should show up again.

Comment: actually i tried this last night on my home PC and go this Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed. So why is it coming up in the first place.

Comment: then just delete everything in reinstall it again  note dont delete your workspace.