# Android SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have downloaded the Android Studio but when I want to create a new project, an error pops up saying "Your Android SDK is out date or missing templates..

How do I fix this project, or how do I update the SDK in the Android Studio?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575988/android-studio-sdk-is-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

[image: Update]

Click here and update your SDK ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can update your sdk in many ways.

**1.** Download sdk from developer [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

**SET:**`file->project Structure->in android SDK section  set custom path of sdk`

2.`Tools->Android->SDK manager update sdk`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like permission problem. Someone who packed Android Studio, has the original files under non-root account. If you unpack it as root, the files and dirs has no permission for "other" (just for owner). The person who is packing Android Studio knows a lot about Android and Java, but not much about Unix permissions (uch!). There are two possible solutions:

a) unpack android-studio-bundle-...-linux.tgz as normal user, not as root (this has an advantage - you will be able to update Andriod Studio by clicking menu; but this is generally stupid because you are open to malware attack)

b) fix read permissions for files and dirs for whole android-studio directory with something like: chmod -R 755 /opt/android-studio (not ideal because all files has "x" then, but it  works)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue in linux. I am new user to android without any projects, I followed the instructions in https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html , Once I got    to "In Eclipse or Android Studio, click SDK Manager  in the toolbar", I noticed that from the welcome screen configure> Sdk Manager was greyed out. To solve,closed the program and relaunched as a sudo/superuser.  Then go to Project Defaults> Project Structure. In the Android SDK location field go to "directory-where-you-installed-android-studio/android-studio/sdk'. Once done, click ok. Then close and relaunch the program once more. The SDK manger should be active now